# Create a parent container for a single window in i3

Tags: i3

Is there a simple way to create a single child container wrapping a selected window in i3 ?

Let's say following is my container hierarchy:

```
         Root
       /      \
TabContainer   Vim
    /    \
 Brave1   Firefox
```

I'd like to create a container for vim:

```
         Root
       /      \
TabContainer   (Tab)Container
    /    \          \
 Brave1   Firefox   Vim
```

So that now I can open devtools for brave/firefox and shift it right into the same tab layout as vim without needing to juggle windows across multiple workspaces.

```
             Root
       /            \
TabContainer      (Tab)Container
    /    \            /       \
 Brave1   Firefox  Devtools   Vim
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by focusing on Vim and then sending the `split v` or `split h` command.  Now the next window you create should be in a unique container alongside Vim.  There may be a more direct way to wrap a container around a single window that I don't know about, though.